# Can SPARQL modify data like SQL? Or is it read-only?

Tags: wikidata, sparql

Despite being a query language, SQL can perform DELETE/UPDATE/INSERT operations.

Similarly, can SPARQL modify data?

If find SPARQL convenient so I would like to use it to modify data, for instance to add a property to all items that satisfy a particular WHERE clause.

Is it possible? If not, are there SPARQL extensions to do that? Is any such extension usable on live Wikidata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [SPARQL Update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARUL). [It doesn't seem to be supported by Wikidata Query Service.](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20dc%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%3E%0AINSERT%20DATA%0A%7B%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fexample%2Fbook3%3E%20dc%3Atitle%20%20%20%20%22A%20new%20book%22%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dc%3Acreator%20%20%22A.N.Other%22%20.%0A%7D)